Fix Google Sheets formula so it will append the header title of each column it is pulling data from, instead of just the first column's title
I have a Google Sheet formula designed to pull the top 5 values out of a range of columns, display each of them separated by columns, calculate them as a percentage of a reference column, and append the name of the column each percentage is from. The formula looks like this:
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(C$1:AE$1, MATCH(LARGE(C2:AE2, SEQUENCE(5, 1)), C2:AE2, 0) + COLUMN(C2) - 3) & ": " & ROUND(LARGE(C2:AE2, SEQUENCE(5, 1)) / AH2 * 100, 2) & "%"))

It works correctly to pull the values, but it appends the name of "ColumnC" in front of every percentage, instead of the column title that the value was from.
E.g: the result returned should be something like:
"Apples: 20%, Oranges: 15%, Lemons: 12%, Bananas: 10%, Grapes: 7%"
but it returns:
"Apples: 20%, Apples: 15%, Apples: 12%, Apples: 10%, Apples: 7%"
Is there a way I can fix this so it pulls the appropriate column header name each % falls under instead?
Thanks!
Edit: sample data looks like this, sorry if I balls this up as first time trying:



CODE
FruitBasket_Name
Apple
Banana
Peach
Pear
Grapefruit
Plum
Grape
Mango
Watermelon
Lemon
Lime
Mandarin
Jackfruit
Blueberry
Pineapple
Kiwi
Boysenberry
Fig
Lychee
Blood Orange
Papaya
Passionfruit
Cantaloupe
Serbian
Cranberry
Cherry
Clementine
Persimmon
Satsuma
Raspberry
Rockmelon
TotalFruit
Top5




10001
FruitBasket_1
12
3
0
0
0
10
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
8
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
5
33
Apple: 36.36%, Apple: 30.3%, Apple: 24.24%, Apple: 9.09%, Apple: 0%


10002
FruitBasket_2
606
15
179
276
8
379
87
12
66
98
44
118
964
4
94
77
160
13
13
40
54
14
80
90
7
69
10
175
6
1313
151
4200





You shouldn't combine Exel tags with Google-sheets, although similar, there's a lot of subtle differences. Also, try to include sample data through text, Markdown Table generator can help you with this.

Post sample data to the post.

Try the following QUERY() formula-
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,QUERY(SORT(TRANSPOSE({C1:AG1;INDEX(C2:AG2/AH2)}),2,0),"limit 5 format Col2 '0.00%'"))


Edit: Adding updated formula using BYROW().

=BYROW(C2:AG,LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTIF(r,">0")=0,,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,QUERY(TRANSPOSE({C1:AG1;INDEX(r/CHOOSEROWS(AH:AH,ROW(r)))}),"order by Col2 DESC limit 5 format Col2 '0.00%'")))))



We can remove SORT() function using order by  clause inside QUERY() function. Lets try =TEXTJOIN(", ",1,QUERY(TRANSPOSE({C1:AG1;INDEX(C2:AG2/AH2)}),"order by Col2 DESC limit 5 format Col2 '0.00%'")).

Thanks - this works for row 1 only, but I'd like to be able to apply it to all rows in whole column & dynamically pull for the entire sheet if possible?

@GeezerTD Try my edited answer please.

yes this looks like it worked for the whole table, thank you so much!

@GeezerTD Glad to know! If it works then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.

sorry, is there a way to adjust so the label "Apple" has a colon after it, instead of a comma? E.g: "Apple: 36%, Plum: 30%, Banana: 9%," instead of "Apple, 36%, Plum, 30%" etc?

You can try this:
=JOIN(", ",LET(x, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(HSTACK(TOCOL(C1:AG1),TOCOL(C2:AG2)),2,FALSE),5,2), y,BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(x,2), LAMBDA(r, CONCATENATE(ROUND((r/AH2)*100,0),"%"))), BYROW(HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(x,1),y), LAMBDA(t,JOIN(":",t)))))

Sample Output:

Please make sure that the range is going to be changed accordingly.
Update formula: For dynamic spilling formula you can use this.
=BYROW(C2:AG15, LAMBDA(zz, JOIN(", ",LET(x, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(HSTACK(TOCOL(C1:AG1),TOCOL(zz)),2,FALSE),5,2), y,BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(x,2), LAMBDA(r, CONCATENATE(ROUND((r/AH2)*100,0),"%"))), BYROW(HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(x,1),y), LAMBDA(t,JOIN(":",t))))))) 

Note: To change the range it is going to process, please change the C2:AG15 accordingly.
Here's another Formula:
=LET(x, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(HSTACK(TOCOL($C$1:$AG$1),TOCOL(C2:AG2)),2,FALSE),5,2), y,BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(x,2), LAMBDA(r, CONCATENATE(ROUND((r/AH2)*100,0),"%"))), JOIN(", ",BYROW(HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(x,1),y), LAMBDA(t,JOIN(": ",t)))))

I edited the formula so you can drag it down easily on your project. I made it this way for you to be able to apply this on your sheet it seems that there are a lot of things unknown with your current data set.
Sample Output:

Reference:
Join
Let
ByRow

Yes that worked - thanks! If I want to change it so I can fill the entirety of column AI with the formula as the actual table has around 100 rows of data, is there something that needs to change? As ctrl-D attempt to fill the entire column doesn't work, only for row 2

@GeezerTD We can significantly simply the formula using QUERY() function with limit clause. You may test my answer.

I have updated my solution; please test it on your end and confirm if it works.

@Alma_Matters - thanks; your updated version works for filling with the labels in the rest of the column, but now doesn't calculate the percentages correctly? Also any idea how to make a "space" after the label & percentage? E.g: returns "Apples:36%" instead of "Apples: 36%"

I have created a new formula. You can check and try it on your end. I hope it works for you.
